# Copy files from fileserver uri to local folder in C# .NET 6

Tags: c#, copy, .net-6.0

In my c# .NET 6 Application i am currently facing the following problem:

I have a directory on a fileserver that contains some files and
i want all those files to be copied to a local folder on my machine somehow like this:

```cs
public static void CopyFilesFromSourceToTarget()
{
    var source = new DirectoryInfo("http://my/fileserver/directory");
    var target = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\my\local\directory");

    foreach (var file in source.GetFiles())
    {
        var targetPath = Path.Combine(target.FullName, file.Name);
        file.CopyTo(targetPath, overwrite: true);
    }
}
```

I know this code can't work because the `source` is not a path but an URI and i should probably work with  a `HttpClient`.

But when i do:

```cs
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(source);
string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

the `responseString` contains html content and that just seems wrong to me...

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index of /my/fileserver/directory/</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
        <h1>Index of /my/fileserver/directory/</h1>
        <hr>
            <pre>
                <a href="../">../</a>
                <a href="file1.xsd">file1.xsd</a> 04-May-2023 06:19   9815
                <a href="file2.xml">file2.xml</a> 04-May-2023 06:19   66960
                <a href="file3.xml">file3.xml</a> 04-May-2023 06:19   204413
            </pre>
        <hr>
    </body>
</html>
```

I mean yes, it would not be too hard to parse the html and get those filenames to append them to the `source` directory string, but i can't be the only one with that problem that there is no other solution...

So is there an elegant way to copy all those fileserver files to my local folder?

Comment: response.Content should be your file if not and you get something as html its probably an error message you should take a look at. By the way response returns also StatusCode you should check. Then you know if its your file or something else. Don't expect that things simply work.

Comment: I've edited my question and added the html response... Code is 200

Comment: Missed that you want a file listing (at first) and not a file. That seems something server specific and you need to look up the specific http server what and how he does it.

Answer (score 0):

I would invoke the appropriate command line in your OS (let's say wget or robocopy) from c# and do not write any other code.

Comment: Good idea but the code should be runnable on all platforms... windows and linux mainly

Comment: Then, I would have two command lines and switch based on platform.